# How to concatenate a macro name with a parameter of it to create a new macro?

Tags: c

To reduce the binary size, I want to remove logs(based on log levels) at compile time.
Current code:

```
#define LOG(level,msg) log_write(level,msg)
```

and it is used everywhere as LOG(ERROR, msg), LOG(INFO, msg) etc.

I tried to segregate logs (without modifying at logging locations)

```
#define LOG(level,msg)  LOG_##level(level,mgs)
```

and then introduce new compilation flags (LOG_LEVEL_x)
and remove at compile time based on the selected log levels as below:

```
#ifdef LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG
#define LOG_DEBUG(level,msg) log_write(level,msg)
#else
#define LOG_DEBUG(level,msg)
```

Now, the problem is

```
#define LOG(level,msg)  LOG_##level(level,msg)
```

gives error as below
**error: pasting "LOG_" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token.**

How can I fix this? Any solution without modifying all the logging locations?

Comment: Call me crazy, but why would you even want to do this? Dead branch elimination will automatically prune conditional log statements whose condition is const false

Comment: sed your code replacing `LOG(level,` by `LOG_level(`. Create a separate macro for every possible `LOG_level`, You can then perfectly fine steer code creation by `undef`ing those macros as you like.

Comment: @alk This is a much better suggestion IMO.

Comment: You need to show the non-working code that produces the error message – an MCVE ([MCVE]).  I don't get your error message from a number of minor variants of what's in your question (there's an `#endif` missing, for example, and you don't show the actual macro invocation that triggers the compilation).  But, under some not very onerous conditions (no `#define DEBUG` without a value, for example), it seems to work for me.

Comment: `#define LOG(level,msg)  LOG_##level(level,msg)` definitely works.